# How can I print conditional statement in an array

Tags: c, loops, conditional-statements

I am trying to identify the prime and composite value from an array. But in conditional statement, it prints only if value not else.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a[5], i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &a[i]);
    }
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        for (j = 2; j <= a[i] / 2; j++)
        {
            if (a[i] % j == 0)
            {
                printf("%d is not a prime number\n", a[i]);
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                printf("%d is a prime number\n", a[i]);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number is prime only if for all `for (j = 2; j <= a[i] / 2; j++)` the conditional `a[i] % j == 0` is false. What you need to do is the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int isNumberPrime(int value){
    if(value == 1) return 0;
    for (int j = 2; j <= value / 2; j++)
        if (value % j == 0)
            return 0;
    return 1;
}

int main()
{
    int a[5];
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &a[i]);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {    
        if(isNumberPrime(a[i]))
           printf("%d is a prime number\n", a[i]);
        else
           printf("%d is not a prime number\n", a[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```